# Copy same rectangle from source bitmap to destination bitmap

Tags: vb.net, graphics, bitmap, drawing

In a usercontrol (a grid), I have a bitmap ("_Buffer").

Whenever a part of the usercontrol should be drawn, I want to copy the specific part from "_Buffer" to "e.Graphics":

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

    If Not _Buffer Is Nothing Then
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(_Buffer, e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y, e.ClipRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
    End If

End Sub
```

However, I'm experiencing strange graphics artifacts and strange drawing positions.

I would therefore like to ask if my use of "e.Graphics.DrawImage" is correct or what would be the correct syntax to copy a certain portion (defined by a rectangle) of a bitmap onto the same portion (same rectangle) of another bitmap.

Comment: Your description including "strange artifacts" is vague.  This a case where and image might be useful

Comment: It's too difficult to explain what exactely goes wrong. A screenshot wouldn't help. I could best describe it as "Image is drawn at wrong place". Because it's difficult to explain, I was "hoping" that simply my use of DrawImage is wrong in this case.

Comment: For the record `e.ClipRectangle` represents only the invalidated part of the control, and it's variable. It could represent just a small piece, or the entire control.

Comment: On the other hand, `DrawImage(image As System.Drawing.Image, destRect As System.Drawing.Rectangle, srcX As Integer, srcY As Integer, srcWidth As Integer, srcHeight As Integer, srcUnit As System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit)`  but its just a guess

Comment: Where do you want to paint it?  e.ClipRectangle.X and Y is probably a long shot to be the coordinates you want.  And the e.ClipRectangle is also probably the wrong dimensions.